# <br /> must stay instead of \u003cbr / when using google translate

Tags: php, json

I use function translate as shown below. In the text there are many 
 tags and they are changed into \u003cbr / after translation.

Example:
Super Preis - Leistungsverhältnis.

## Das bekommen Sie nur bei uns !

Super prijs - . Geld \u003cbr /\u003e U ons \u003cbr /\u003e

Question: how can prevent that the text 
 tags are not changed and stays after translations as 
 tags.

```
function translate($text, $from = 'de', $to = 'nl'){
 $texto_traducri = urlencode($text);
 $query = "http://translate.google.nl/translate_a/t?client=t&text=$texto_traducri%0A%0A&hl=$from&sl=$from&tl=$to&multires=1&prev=enter&oc=5&ssel=3&tsel=6&sc=1";
 $response = file_get_contents(
    $query,
    null,
    stream_context_create(
        array(
            'http'=>array(
            'method'=>"GET",
            'header'=>"Referer: http://translate.google.nl/\r\n"
            )
        )
    )
);
$p_separador = strpos($response,'","');
$p_separador = strpos($response,"]]");
$s_previo = substr($response,3,($p_separador));
$a_previo = explode("],[",$s_previo);
$txt_sum = '';
    foreach($a_previo as $s_cadenaparcial){
        $s_cadenaparcial = str_replace("]", "", $s_cadenaparcial);
        $s_cadenaparcial = str_replace("[", "", $s_cadenaparcial);
        $a_cadena = explode('","',$s_cadenaparcial);
        $txt_sum.=substr($a_cadena[0],1);
        }
    $tagresult = $txt_sum;
```

$tagresult = htmlspecialchars_decode($tagresult);

```
return $tagresult;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`\u003c` and `\u003e` represent the unicode values for `<` and `>`.

You could simply convert them back to normal characters.

Here is an example of how to do that:

```
<?
    function uconverter($matches) {
        return html_entity_decode('&#' . hexdec($matches[1]) . ';', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
    }
    function decode_uchars($str) {
        return preg_replace_callback('/\\\\u([0-9A-Fa-f]{4})/', uconverter, $str);
    }


    $in = 'Super prijs - . Geld \u003cbr /\u003e U ons \u003cbr /\u003e';
    $out = decode_uchars($in); // Super prijs - . Geld <br /> U ons <br />

    echo $out;
?>
```

Comment: Will test it tomorrow it was a tiring day. Thanks anyway.